# Call a method from an activity from an adapter

Tags: android

I am working with an adapter which has several buttons on each item of the ListView. I have, for example two buttons. One for save and another for delete.

When I click on them, I want the adapter to refresh. I have a method on my activity that does that: Update the adapter. I made it since I couldn't make the Notify methods of the adapter work.

I am sending the Activity to the adapter as a parameter and then call the update method from the adapter since I am setting the OnClick methods of each button in the adapter.

The problem is that it doesnt seem to work always. I am guessing it has to do something about the cycle of the activity and Android cleaning memory however I can't seem to understand where is the problem.

I am aware this is some ugly way of doing it, so what should be the best way of doing this?

Summary: I need to refresh the adapter from the adapter itself when I delete an item of the ListView or update it (BaseAdapter)

Edit:
I am adding some code. This is my constructor of my adapter:

```
public SpendingPlanAdapter(Context context, SpendingPlan sp, int month, int year, money.activities.SpendingPlan act)
```

Inside the adapter I have an OnCLickListener attached to a button. I am calling the update method like this (Result is the result of a database insert):

```
if (result){
                    Toast.makeText(context, context.getResources().getString(R.string.succesfully_deleted), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                  
                    act.updateAdapter();                    
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(context, context.getResources().getString(R.string.oops), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
```

And this is my UpdateAdapter method:

```
public void updateAdapter(){        
        SpendingPlanAdapter adapter = new SpendingPlanAdapter(getApplicationContext(), currentSp, currentMonth, currentYear, this);
        limitList.setAdapter(adapter);  
    }
```

Comment: The best method is still calling notify* methods. Could you show your code so that someone can see what is the problem with calling them.

Comment: I added some code that might help to understand the problem. Calling notify* methods inside the adapter seem to do nothing, although this is something that happens on every adapter. Usually I just create a new one and assign it again to the view.

Comment: And you are positive that in your OnClick() the data for your adapter do change? You may want to log your adapter's getCount() for example to make sure that indeed your adapter sees a recently added data

Comment: Well, I am deleting a row. And I am pretty sure it does it since if I go to another activity and come back, the row is gone. I have a "month bar" that whenever I change the month, it updates the adapter. When I click on the button, it shows the toast however the row is still there. If I go to another month and come back (even w/o leaving the activity) the row is gone. Its clearly the adapter that is not calling the method, which is strange because sometimes if works. Sometimes it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `updateAdapter()` like this

```
(SpendingPlan (context)).updateAdapter();
```